# How to make a function wait until a function return a value using node.js

Tags: node.js, express, callback

This code return an error before executing the `sendTransaction` function.
I have used a callback but it doesn't work also.

Here is the code that I have written

```
var mytoken= MyContract.at(contractAddress);    
router.get('/test',function (req, res, next)
 {
   res.render('test.ejs');
 });
  //send token
router.post('/test', function(req, res, next) {
     var recieverAdd = req.body.to;
     var from=req.body.from;
     var amount = req.body.amount;
     var bool= web3.personal.unlockAccount(web3.eth.accounts[0],"yosra");   

     mytoken.transfer.sendTransaction(from,recieverAdd,amount, {from:eth.accounts[0],gas:500000},function (error, result)
    {
        callback(result);

    });
});
```

Comment: "An error" is not a useful piece of information. Always include the **exact** error message you're getting (including stack trace), verbatim.

Comment: @Mat how can I include the exact error please!?

Comment: Copy the error you get, and paste it here.

Comment: The solution to this is simple: change `callback(result)` to `res.end(result)` or if you have a template you want to render `res.render(template, {result: result})`